# What was the equivalent of "Shoulder Arms, Fire!" for archers in Ancient Rome?

Tags: warfare, roman-empire

Up until firearms were invented, armies used archers for similar purposes. A well-timed volley, when one can't see the sky for the flying arrows, can have a demoralizing effect on the enemy in addition to the physical damage it is likely to cause.

In order for a volley to be well-timed, the archers had to take aim and shoot simultaneously, following a single order given by a single commander. Ever since the advent of firearms that order has been "Fire!"

Now imagine, say, a Roman centurion, his back to the archers standing in formation, waiting for his signal. He's watching the enemy's movements. Now he raises his hand. He waits. At last he judges that the right moment has come. He shouts a single word, sonorously enough to be heard by every single one of his archers ... What is that word?

Comment: For arrows, I suspect it would be "shoot" or "loose" or even "release".

Comment: Don't know what about Latin, but in Russian "стрелять" (to shoot) is definitely derived from "стрела" (arrow).

Comment: @SteveBird: So "Loose!" would be something King Harold, or one of his commanders, would should at the Battle of Hastings?

Comment: @user4419802: I'm more interested in commands shouted in English.

Comment: @Ricky [SE:English “Fire” a weapon before firearms existed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158711/fire-a-weapon-before-firearms-existed)

Comment: I've seen it. Neither answer strikes me as credible. Try shouting "Fire!" so that someone standing 100 feet from you could hear it. Easy, right? Now try shouting "release!" or "loose!" Not so easy anymore. It's all about the vowels.

Comment: @Ricky `The only documentable medieval words of command for archers seem to have been "Knock"[sic] and "Streach"[sic].` That is, we may speculate, but have no sources. On the matter of vowels, there could be some difference in medieval pronounce, or even special "military" form.

Comment: @Ricky `So "Loose!" would be something King Harold, or one of his commanders, would should at the Battle of Hastings?` Probably not. [Loose](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=loose&searchmode=none) is known only from 1200s. Also "Release" is impossible, as it's certainly of French origin.

Comment: @user4419802 French is a Romance language... derived from Latin. There's likely a Latin equivalent.

Comment: @Axelrod Eng. "Release" - Fr. "[Re]laissier / [Re]laisser" - Lat. "Laxare". Not suitable for "shooting", anyway.

Comment: @user4419802 However, Russian officer would shout "Пли!" which is literally "make fire".

Comment: @user58697 Could you please change your name to something more human-sounding? Goodness, we're people, not units. And tell the other guy to do the same.

Comment: @user58697 Yes, but both "Огонь" and "Пли" are about firearms, just like "Fire" in English.

Comment: Possibly of interest, [a Grecian sling-shot with the word "Dexa" molded into it](http://www.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=399876&partId=1). Translation: "Catch!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably a Roman Centurion would have used the Latin word [sagittō](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2052318).

**CAUTION** - I neither speak Latin nor do I study etymology, so what exists in an online Latin translator today may have little or no bearing on the archaic Latin used two millenia ago.

sagitto, no perf., ātum, 1, v. n. and a. [id.]. Neutr., to discharge arrows, to shoot with arrows (post-Aug. for sagittam jacere, etc.): hos equitare et sagittare docent, Just. 41, 2, 5; Curt. 7, 5, 42; Sol. 19 med.; Vulg. Psa. 10, 2; 63, 4.

Comment: BTW. Roman legionaries had no bows at all. Only some auxiliary units (sagittariorum) spesialised in archery. Not sure, if those auxiliaries were really commanded by centurions. Moreover, it could be that many guys in auxilias didn't speak Latin at all, so they got commands in their native language.

Comment: Roman activities of any sort were always coordinated, at least in theory. Legionnaires did not drag rams and catapults on their backs either. So what.

Comment: @Ricky Legionaries had only javelins (pilum), which they used for mid-range attack (about 30 meters). So they just stayed in place, while archers were shooting.

Comment: That's correct. Someone had to give orders to the archers, though. It wasn't like, oh, look, the legionnaires are standing still, so maybe it's time we let loose a few arrows at the enemy, wherever this enemy is.

Comment: @Ricky Well, the archer unit commander may spoke Latin. But when he commanded to his soldiers "shoot", he, probably, said this in Greek (cf. [Cretan archers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretan_archers)). BTW. Roman nobles spoke Greek too.

Comment: Yes, not really, and yes. Commands were generally given in Latin, and weren't difficult to memorize regardless of what language this or that warrior's mother tongue. Elite units of specialists have existed throughout history, but shooting arrows ain't rocket science, and various great shooting techniques and legendary archers existed everywhere and did not need lessons from the Cretans. Greek was the language of culture in the Empire, just like French was until very recently and still is in certain milieus.

Comment: The only French word non-French military have used over the past five centuries is "hurrah," or variations on the same theme, such as "huzzah."

Comment: @Ricky: Seems to me you are forgetting all of: corps, fusilier, musket, musketeer; sergeant, corporal, lieutenant, lancer, corsair, and uncountable others adapted into other European languages from French